# the right syntax for arraylist and scanner

Tags: java

```
String password;
String user;
ArrayList<User> Userlist = new ArrayList<User>();
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

while (true) {
    System.out.println("enter username:");
    Userlist.add(user);
    user = input.nextline();

    System.out.println("enter password:");
    Userlist.add(password);
    password = input.nextline();
}
```

I am trying to save 2 Strings(user and password) into an ArrayList using the scanner. i just want to know the right syntax for it.

Comment: There are a lot of documentation pages and tutorials on this.  Please review and give it a shot.

Comment: You should perhaps first get the user input and then add it to the list

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to make an array of Users, so you would need to create a User object first:

```
while (true) {
        System.out.println("enter username:");
        userName = input.nextline();
        System.out.println("enter password:");
        password = input.nextline();
        User user = new User(userName, password); //keep in mind this required an apporopriate constructor in the User class
        Userlist.add(user);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several mistakes in here. First you can't assign what you put into the console to a type of `User`. Either create such an object first or switch to `String`. Also: the order of adding the string to the list is wrong. You need to first read from input and **then** add that to the list. Finally there doesn't even exist such a method as `nextline`, it's actually `nextLine`. That being said, here are two variants to solve your problem:

- using a type `User` with appropriate constructor being setup:

  ```
  class User {
    String user; String password;
    User(String user, String password) {
      this.user = user; this.password = password;
    }
  }
  ```

  with the corresponding code then being:

  ```
  String password; String user;
  ArrayList<User> userlist = new ArrayList<>();
  Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
  while (true)
  {
    System.out.println("enter username:");
    user = input.nextLine();

    System.out.println("enter password:");
    password = input.nextLine();

    userlist.add(new User(user, password));
  }
  ```
- just putting everything into one single list, whose generic type then should be `String`:

  ```
  String password; String user;
  ArrayList<String> userlist = new ArrayList<>();
  Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);

  while (true)
  {
      System.out.println("enter username:");
      user = input.nextLine();
      userlist.add(user);

      System.out.println("enter password:");
      password = input.nextLine();
      userlist.add(password);
  }
  ```

Comment: I don't think having a list of Strings with usernames and passwords in it is what the code is supposed to do. @AleksW's answer provides a better approach.

Comment: ... well... right... I also added that... but problably too late ;-)

Comment: thank you for your reply! i tried to implement your version but the compiler is giving me an "cant find symbol" error. i´ve tried the first alternative you´ve posted. did i forget something?

Comment: did you setup the imports correctly? do you have such a `User`-class in place?

Comment: adding another class named user lead to another compiler error. i can post my setup in another comment.

Comment: nevermind i´ve made a mistake. thanks again for your help !

Comment: small question aside: what do i need to add to this class if i want to use this method in another class. my main goal is to write a program that can save username and password, use the Rot13 method on it and save it in an array. i was thinking the get and set method. or using this so i can refer to it in my main method